# Redraw Google Chart Without Refresh The Page

Tags: angular, typescript, google-visualization

I have a button for refresh the data on page if api has new data. It able to refresh my datatable but not redrawing google charts. Im using this module for integrate google charts to my project [Ng2GoogleCharts](https://github.com/gmazzamuto/ng2-google-charts).

Do you know any possible way to redraw chart or delete that chart and create again?

this is how i create chart on the html page;

```
<google-chart [data]="mixChartData" #chart></google-chart>
```

and i declare mixChartData on .ts file like that;

```
this.mixChartData={
      chartType: 'LineChart',
      dataTable: this.mixChart,
      options: this.mixOptions
    }
```

Comment: in the [reference documentation](https://www.devrandom.it/software/ng2-google-charts/) under _Advanced Usage_ from the link you provided, you can simply call the `draw` method on the component --> `ccComponent.draw();`

Comment: oh, thank you so much. i should read docs more careful next time. i guess i deserved a couple of downvotes hahaha

Comment: "import { GoogleChartInterface } from 'ng2-google-charts/google-charts-interfaces';" is not working...

Answer (score 1):

To force a redraw, on the `GoogleChartInterface` which in your case is `this.mixChartData` there is a `component` property which has a `draw()` method

```js
this.mixChartData.component.draw();
```

You may also pass the data to redraw with

```js
this.mixChartData.component.draw(this.mixChartData);
```

Answer (score -1):

I've been strugling with this issue for days, this is detailed version of the above solution :

In your HTML:

```
   <google-chart #mychart [data]="toDoChart"></google-chart>
```

In the component

```
  @ViewChild('mychart ', {static: false}) mychart;
```

Then insert the following code where you want to performe an update to the chart depanding on your logic:

```
 updateToDoChart(){    
   this.mychart.draw();
 }
```

Comment: I am forced to add a type to mychart (Member 'mychart' implicitly has an 'any' type).
Infering a type  (i.e. { draw: () => void; } ) is ugly and doesn't resolve the issue: A run time exception:
ERROR TypeError: this.mychart.draw is not a function